# Backport provider packages for Airflow 1.10.12

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow 1.10.12. Currently, I need to connect to Azure Blob Storage and copy some files to Google Cloud Storage. After some research i found we can install backport providers for azure and its dependencies(google) for airflow 1.10.12. So, my question is will any of the existing DAGs that uses from airflow.contrib become invalid if i install this package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

providers are how Airflow decoples code that isn't core related into separated packages. This allow faster and independent release cycle of providers and Airflow core.

In order to ease migration to Airflow 2 - `backport providers` were released. These are classes that are compatible with Airflow 1.10.x classes in `contrib` aren't affected by this.
`providers` are just an additional package that contains new classes/ updated version of classes from `contrib`.

To be noted that there are no more releases of backport providers packages. Thus it's highly recommended that you will upgrade to Airflow 2 as soon as possible so that you will be able to use providers packages.