# how to use BigQueryHook to read data from another project

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, hook

we have airflow composer instance in GCP project A and our BQ dataset is present in Project B. When we are trying to read data from BQ we getting error. we are writing hook as  hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)

how can we pass the project name B in this BigQueryHook function

Answer (score 1):

First `bigquery_conn_id` is deprecated. You should use `gcp_conn_id`.

Project Id is a property of GCP connection as you can see in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html#configuring-the-connection). If you set it on the connection level Airflow uses it. However if needed you can override it on in the hook.

```
BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id='bigquery_default', project_id='other_project')
```

You can check the source code that is doing the override [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/eaa8ac72fc901de163b912a94dbe675045d2a009/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py#L403-L432).

Comment: Thanks @Elad, i tried this approach but getting error "ERROR - __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gcp_conn_id'"

Comment: Sounds like you are running old version of the class. Are you importing from google provider or `contrib`? Which airflow version are you running?

Comment: from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook..i am using 1.10.15+composer

Comment: This is outdated version. You should install google backport provider and import the class from it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68236614/14624409